# Trying to understand a piece of inline arm assembly from the linux kernel

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, gnu-assembler, arm64

I'm trying to understand what this piece of inline assembly does, which is generated from the C `DEFINE` macro:

```
#define DEFINE(sym, val) asm volatile("\n->" #sym " %0 " #val : : "i" (val))

#define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER)  ((size_t)&((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)
```

It's used in some piece of magic for doing AArch64 `smc` calls in the [linux-imx](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/tree/imx_4.9.51_imx8m_ga_var01) kernel fork. The place where the above C macros are used to define the values is [here](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/imx_4.9.51_imx8m_ga_var01/arch/arm64/kernel/asm-offsets.c):

```
// arch/arm64/kernel/asm-offsets.c

int main(void)
{
    (...)
      DEFINE(ARM_SMCCC_RES_X0_OFFS,     offsetof(struct arm_smccc_res, a0));
      DEFINE(ARM_SMCCC_RES_X2_OFFS,     offsetof(struct arm_smccc_res, a2));
      DEFINE(ARM_SMCCC_QUIRK_ID_OFFS,   offsetof(struct arm_smccc_quirk, id));
      DEFINE(ARM_SMCCC_QUIRK_STATE_OFFS,    offsetof(struct arm_smccc_quirk, state));
    (...)
}
```

And later, these defines are used in an assembly macro, [available here](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/imx_4.9.51_imx8m_ga_var01/arch/arm64/kernel/smccc-call.S) (or at least that's what it looks like):

```
// arch/arm64/kernel/smccc-call.S

    .macro SMCCC instr
    .cfi_startproc
    \instr  #0
    ldr x4, [sp]
    stp x0, x1, [x4, #ARM_SMCCC_RES_X0_OFFS]
    stp x2, x3, [x4, #ARM_SMCCC_RES_X2_OFFS]
    ldr x4, [sp, #8]
    cbz x4, 1f /* no quirk structure */
    ldr x9, [x4, #ARM_SMCCC_QUIRK_ID_OFFS]
    cmp x9, #ARM_SMCCC_QUIRK_QCOM_A6
    b.ne    1f
    str x6, [x4, ARM_SMCCC_QUIRK_STATE_OFFS]
1:  ret
    .cfi_endproc
    .endm

ENTRY(__arm_smccc_smc)
    SMCCC   smc
ENDPROC(__arm_smccc_smc)
```

Which, ultimately, is used in practice, e.g. in the [gpc-psci driver](https://github.com/varigit/linux-imx/blob/imx_4.9.51_imx8m_ga_var01/drivers/soc/imx/gpc-psci.c).

I tried to isolate the code into a separate bare-metal AArch64 program to see how the macros are expanded and working in practice, but all I'm getting is compilation errors.

```
// main.c
// the struct arm_smccc_res and others are inserted here to satisfy the compiler

int
main()
{
        DEFINE(ARM_SMCCC_RES_X0_OFFS,      offsetof(struct arm_smccc_res, a0));
        DEFINE(ARM_SMCCC_RES_X2_OFFS,      offsetof(struct arm_smccc_res, a2));
        DEFINE(ARM_SMCCC_QUIRK_ID_OFFS,    offsetof(struct arm_smccc_quirk, id));
        DEFINE(ARM_SMCCC_QUIRK_STATE_OFFS, offsetof(struct arm_smccc_quirk, state));
        return 0;
}

// gcc output

/tmp/cccqaaY3.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cccqaaY3.s:459: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `-'
/tmp/cccqaaY3.s:464: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `-'
/tmp/cccqaaY3.s:469: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `-'
/tmp/cccqaaY3.s:474: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `-'
```

The `offsetof` macro is self-explanatory, but I'm having trouble understanding the use of stringization and `->` in the `DEFINE` macro.

Any ideas what is it expanded to, or how to successfuly compile this?

Comment: The [macro] tag was the least important of these... couldn't fit inline-assembly

Comment: Use `gcc -S` on the source file to generate the *assembly* for that file. Presumably the `DEFINE`s only make sense in the middle of an assembly file - that's what the `asm volatile` is for to ensure that they don't get moved around...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get errors because that file is not supposed to be compiled to object. It's only used to generate assembly output which is then processed to create a header `asm_offsets.h`. This header is what is then included elsewhere. You can find it in `include/generated`. The rules that create it are in the top level `KBuild`:

```
# Kbuild for top-level directory of the kernel
# This file takes care of the following:
# 1) Generate bounds.h
# 2) Generate timeconst.h
# 3) Generate asm-offsets.h (may need bounds.h and timeconst.h)
# 4) Check for missing system calls
# 5) Generate constants.py (may need bounds.h)

# Default sed regexp - multiline due to syntax constraints
define sed-y
        "/^->/{s:->#\(.*\):/* \1 */:; \
        s:^->\([^ ]*\) [\$$#]*\([-0-9]*\) \(.*\):#define \1 \2 /* \3 */:; \
        s:^->\([^ ]*\) [\$$#]*\([^ ]*\) \(.*\):#define \1 \2 /* \3 */:; \
        s:->::; p;}"
endef
```

You can see it uses `sed` to turn the assembly output into a header. The temporary assembly file can be found in `arch/<arch>/kernel/asm-offsets.s`.  Sample lines look like:

```
->pt_regs_bx $40 offsetof(struct pt_regs, bx)   #
->pt_regs_cx $88 offsetof(struct pt_regs, cx)   #
->pt_regs_dx $96 offsetof(struct pt_regs, dx)   #
```

Note this isn't valid assembly syntax, but the compiler doesn't care, it mindlessly emits whatever you put in `asm` blocks after doing the argument substitutions. The `sed` command then transforms them so the matching lines in the header look like:

```
#define pt_regs_bx 40 /* offsetof(struct pt_regs, bx)   # */
#define pt_regs_cx 88 /* offsetof(struct pt_regs, cx)   # */
#define pt_regs_dx 96 /* offsetof(struct pt_regs, dx)   # */
```